# Cannot parse EJS array passed into the bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, ejs

I have an EJS array of String that I want to pass to a jquery function through data attribute. This is how I am passing it:

```
<td colspan="1" align="left" class="openModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" 
                    data-reason=<%= systemp[i].REASON %> > click here </td>
```

Below function is invoked when `click here` is clicked and the data attribute is passed:

```
 $('.openModal').click(function(){
        var reason=$(this).data('reason');
        //what to write here
        for(let i=0;i<reason.length;++i)
          console.log(reason[i]);
      })
```

Suppose `REASON` array contains this: `["My","Name","is","XYZ"]`. The output on console is this:

```
M
y
N
.
.
.
```

I want each element of the array to be printed on each line.
I tried to do the split on REASON array like this:  `reason=reason.split(",");`, but it threw an error that `split is not a function`.

So how can I correctly pass an ejs array through data attribute and parse it corectly?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Start by *looking* at the HTML your EJS is generating. Then worry about why the resulting DOM doesn't give you anything useful.

Comment: The entire array is going as a String where each word is seperated by a comma.

Comment: Cheap solution is to stringify it, issue is the quotes so escape them, which will become messy, personally, I place all REASONs from system in a var in js then pass just the index to data-reason, could also do `data-reason="<%= systemp[i].REASON.join('|') %>"` then split the string by `|`

Comment: Ok so here is the update. ``split`` function is working fine when REASON array has more than one element. But it throws an error when the ``REASON`` array contains just one String, due to some unknown reason. This is after applying Lawrence suggestion.